# Accessing nested formGroupControl, Angular-6

Tags: angular

I am building a form using nested formGroups.

```
this.outerForm = this._formBuilder.group({
  firstFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
    nserNumber: ['', Validators.required]
  }),
  secondFormGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
    blcRoomName: ['', Validators.required],
    tpRoomName: ['', Validators.required],
    codecHostName: ['', Validators.required],
    switchHostname: ['', Validators.required],
    networkReleaseManager: ['', Validators.required],
    availablePorts: ['', Validators.required],
    crqNumber: [''],
    crqCreate: [''],
  })
})
```

I want to access `crqNumber` which is inside `secondFormGroup`, which again inside `outerForm`. How can I access it in my .ts code. I want to change its validation based on some criteria.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to handle this! You need to access the form through `this.outerForm`.

If you use VS Code (or another good Typescript-oriented IDE) it will suggest available methods to you as you type. In this example, I'm setting `crqNumber` to be `required`.

```
this.outerForm.controls.secondFormGroup.controls.crqNumber
  .setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required]));
```

Comment: I am getting Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. No idea why? Its on second controls after secondFormGroup.

Comment: I would explicitly declare secondFormGroup to be type FormGroup

Comment: When dealing with this sometimes I have had to reference the control like so: `this.outerForm['controls'].secondFormGroup`

Comment: this.outerForm.controls.secondFormGroup.get('crqNumber').setValidators(Validators.compose([Validators.required]))   this does not giving error, but no effect in HTML